# How to protect my .pyc files wont get extract out from docker

Tags: django, docker

We have built the Django application dockerized till now there was no issue since we were hosting solution for a client, but now we also need to support in-house deployment which means my docker will be installed at the client machine. I see from the root access I can copy the files inside the docker. How we can save the copy issue from inside docker.

How to add such security in my docker? Please suggest.

Comment: Take a look at [Encrypted and secure docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26006727/encrypted-and-secure-docker-containers) and [How to prohibit access to internals of Docker container?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1116/how-to-prohibit-access-to-internals-of-docker-container) because they are mentioning a few ideas that you might consider to apply to your case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is distributing python source code in Docker secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552706/is-distributing-python-source-code-in-docker-secure)

Comment: You can use cython and convert all python files to .so files. read https://medium.com/@shvkrn.s/101-python-code-obfuscation-using-cython-a6ae3af9b913